# Подсчитать количество созданных объектов для разных пользователей

Tags: mysql, sql

вопрос такой, как мне подсчитать количество созданных объектов (obj_type) для каждого пользователя (user), где event_type = 1?

Имеется таблица такого вида:

| event_type | user | obj_type | obj_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Василий Васильев | 2 | 2000 |
| 1 | Василий Васильев | 4 | 4000 |
| 1 | Василий Васильев | 4 | 4001 |
| 1 | Василий Васильев | 1 | 1000 |
| 1 | Василий Васильев | 3 | 3000 |
| 2 | Василий Васильев | 3 | 3000 |
| 1 | Петр Петров | 2 | 2001 |
| 1 | Петр Петров | 2 | 2002 |

После запроса должна отобразиться информация такого вида:

| user | Count obj_type 1 | Count obj_type 2 | Count obj_type 3 | Count obj_type 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Василий Васильев | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| Петр Петров | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 |

Я пытался сделать так

`select user, count(distinct obj_id) as count1 from logObj where event_type = 1 group by user;`

но такой запрос не посчитает количество для отдельных типов. Была еще такая попытка

`select l.user, (select count(*) from logObj where obj_type=1 and event_type=1) as count1 from logObj l Group by l.user;`

но так он считает не смотря на пользователя.

Буду благодарен любой подсказке для решения задачи! Заранее благодарю

Comment: Количество типов объектов фиксированное или может меняться? В select не представляется возможным динамически создавать колонки в ответе, только строить запрос на стороне приложения.

Comment: У меня таблица некорректно отображается в вопросе, однако в режиме редактирования все нормально было, у вас тоже? https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11213/Почему-некорректно-отображаются-markdown-таблицы-в-вопросе-но-все-хорошо-в-режи

Comment: @mrEvgenX потому что там отступов не было. 4 пробела в начале должно быть что бы таблица стала таблицей (ни или кодом, смотря как считать)

Comment: @Mike В режиме редактирования там красивейшая html-таблица с тэгом `table` и всем необходимым. Согласитесь, хорошо отформатированный текст в тэге `pre` - не то же самое. Разработчикам за компонент редактора "5+", за компонент отображения вопроса "кол".

Comment: @mrEvgenX, количество типов объектов фиксировано. Извиняюсь, за сломанную таблицу, не понимаю почему так получилось

Comment: Выяснили, почему таблица сломана была. Таблицам нужны пустые строки сверху и снизу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, можно использовать конструкцию `CASE WHEN ... THEN ... END` внутри `COUNT`, чтобы посчитать объекты конкретного типа.

При этом может получиться что-то такое http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d2e589/2:

```
SELECT
  user,
  count(case when obj_type=1 then 1 end) as "Count obj_type 1",
  count(case when obj_type=2 then 1 end) as "Count obj_type 2",
  count(case when obj_type=3 then 1 end) as "Count obj_type 3",
  count(case when obj_type=4 then 1 end) as "Count obj_type 4"
FROM logObj
WHERE event_type = 1
GROUP BY user
```

Comment: Да, это определенно, то что мне надо! Я вам невероятно благодарен!